# google map created in jquery not showing in iphone when opened in webview

Tags: jquery, iphone, google-maps

I have shown google map in My Web App through jqueryMobile & jquery.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

 It is showing Well in Web.
  But when I open this page in my iPhone through Web view
 G MAP is not showing at all.
 Please help ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the protocol from SSL (https) to http and the code is working now!

From:

> src="**https**://maps.googleapis.com

To

> src="**http**://maps.googleapis.com